# ASP.NET MVC Razor Roadmap

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-3

I've been searching around on the Goog, but because technology moves so quickly, all my results are seemingly obsolete (brushing the dust off).

I'm looking for the Razor Roadmap for MVC.  I know it went preview, but I'm wondering about the full blown release.  I really want to start using Razor, but I'm not sure what the implications would be if I started building my app using the Preview instead of waiting.

Can anybody shed any current light on this

Comment: it's time to reselect an accepted answer. :)

Comment: +1 for "Goog". *Don't pay any attention to the man behind the curtain! I am the great and powerful Goog!*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Razor was released on 13 Jan 2011 along with several other technologies.  Scott Guthrie [announced it on his blog, here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/13/announcing-release-of-asp-net-mvc-3-iis-express-sql-ce-4-web-farm-framework-orchard-webmatrix.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

### Razor

The razor engine itself probably won't change much. It's just a way of parsing code and it's current method, if it were to change, wouldn't affect much of how the html is parsed

### Mvc 3

There currently is no release date scheduled. The earliest might be the beginning of next month or so. Historically there are a couple months between releases.

I've moved all my projects to MVC 3. However I'm aware that things may change dramatically as this is only a *preview* and not a beta. When the beta comes out you can be pretty sure that there will be very few changes.

So just to recap, only use preview if you don't mind everything possibly breaking when the beta comes out.

I'm always on the look out for any information related to mvc releases and what-not and stay in semi-regular with the team. The last time I talked to Phil Haack was on the 10th of Sept and he said there was still no actual release date scheduled